# C#: перебор редакторов и обращение к редактору (textbox) по числу в имени (textbox01....textbox99)

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется некая Форма в которой размещены редакторы `Sigma` (TextBox) и `MDA` (ChekBox).
Размешены они группами:

```
Sigma01, MDA01
Sigma02, MDA02
...
Sigma99, MDA99
```

Суть вопроса: при установке для чек-бокса значения Checked, редактор Sigma01 должен становится недоступным. Сейчас у меня это реализовано событием:

```
private void mda01_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {if(mda01.Checked) {Sigma01.Enabled = false; }else {Sigma01.Enabled = true;}}
```

Повторять этот же код для всех 99 групп явно как-то неправильно.
Есть ли способ запустить цикл перебора редакторов и при проверке чек-бокса, например с 01 в имени, обращаться к текст-боксу соответствующим номером?

Comment: помещайте каждую пару в `GroupBox` и затем для каждого чекбокса укажите один и тот же обработчик события, который будет кастить `sender` к `CheckBox`, затем брать свойство `Parent` и кастить его к `GroupBox`, и, в конце, находить в его дочерних элементах единтсвенный управляющий элемент типа `TextBox`

Comment: и код метода с условием, что вы написали, можно переписать куда лаконичнее и понятнее: `Sigma01.Enabled = !mda01.Checked;`

Comment: @iiKuzmychov за сокращение спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поместите каждую пару в `GroupBox`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого создайте обработчик события

```
private void SigmaCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

и назначьте его для события `CheckedChanged` у каждого элемента `CheckBox`.

Далее обновите код обработчика:

```
private void SigmaCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkBox     = (CheckBox)sender;
    var groupBox     = (GroupBox)checkBox.Parent;
    var sigmaTextBox = groupBox.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Single();
    
    sigmaTextBox.Enabled = !checkBox.Enabled;
}
```

**P.S.**

Не задумывались про автоматическую генерацию 100 групп вместо создания их вручную?

Comment: Попробовал по другому пути пойти: через 'foreach' перебрал все контролы на форме, вычленил из них именно чек-боксы, вырезал из названия число и устроил  по той же схеме перебор всех текстбоксов по имени Sigma добавляя к имени номер

Comment: ваш способ тоже рабочий, но лично мне он кажется не самым красивым и оптимальным